Two-particle Green's function, possible typo in the book referred?
I'm trying to follow a computation in some QFT book, p64. The goal is to derive the equation of motion for the lesser Green's function $G^<$ defined as
$$
G^< = \mp i {\rm Tr}\left(\rho \Psi^\dagger(\vec{x}',t')\Psi(\vec{x},t) \right) = \mp i \langle \Psi^\dagger(\vec{x}',t')\Psi(\vec{x},t)\rangle.
$$
Such equation of motion reads (for a one particle Hamiltonian $h(t)$ and a two-body interaction with matrix element $V^{(2)}(\vec{x},\vec{\tilde{x}})$)
$$
\left(i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} - h(t) \right)G^<(\vec{x},t,\vec{x}',t') = \int d\vec{\tilde{x}} V^{(2)}(\vec{x},\vec{\tilde{x}})G_{(2)}(\vec{x},t,\vec{\tilde{x}},t,\vec{\tilde{x}},t,\vec{x}',t'),
$$
where
$$
G_{(2)}(\vec{x},t,\vec{\tilde{x}},t,\vec{\tilde{x}},t,\vec{x}',t') = \pm i\langle \Psi(\vec{x},t)\Psi(\vec{\tilde{x}},t)\Psi^\dagger(\vec{\tilde{x}},t)\Psi^\dagger(\vec{x}',t')\rangle.
$$
Basically, my question is how to derive this last equation. In order to derive it, one has to start with the Heisenberg equation for the field operator
$$
i\hbar \frac{\partial \psi(\vec{x},t)}{\partial t} = h(t)\psi(\vec{x},t) + \int d\vec{x}' V^{(2)}(\vec{x},\vec{x}')\psi^\dagger(\vec{x}',t)\psi(\vec{x}',t)\psi(\vec{x},t).
$$
Evidently, it is straightforward to derive the equation for $G_{(2)}$, as one has to multiply by $\rho$, take the trace, and multiply by the factor $\mp i$. However, I want to know if the book has a typo in writing such $G_{(2)}$.
Specifically, I can't see why it has in front a $\pm$ while $G^<$ has a $\mp$. The upper sign is understood for bosons and the lower for fermions. I can see that e.g. anticommuting fermionic destruction operators $\Psi$ will yield a minus sign, but I can't see why a string of bosonic operators can affect the sign coming from $G^<$.
EDIT: I'm trying to figure out if the book has an erratum. I'm not interested in "check-my-work" kind of stuff and is neither a homework question. I'm learning myself the topic, so these type of things always pop-out.

Anticommutation? Flipped order?

DOn't understand the comment.

What do you mean with last equation? Your second or third? In the former case, it is not clear what you've tried. In the latter, it is not clear what you mean.

Last equation = 3rd equation.

Does $\langle\Psi^\dagger\Psi\rangle=-\langle\Psi\Psi^\dagger\rangle$? Or something related.

Yes and no. For fermions, the minus sign you mention comes from the anticommutation rule for the fermionic operators. However, my struggle is for the bosonic case, where the operators commute and in this case $\langle \Psi^\dagger \Psi\rangle = \langle \Psi \Psi^\dagger\rangle$.

Unless I am making a very stupid mistake :(

I obtain the same results as you do with the additional minus sign and its the same as in "Nonequilibrium Many-Body Theory of Quantum Systems" from Stefanucci and van Leeuwen in Chapter 4/5. Note they have a different convention on ( -i ) and argument ordering in the definition of Green functions. Therefore, I would suppose there is a typo in Rammer.
